# Loop Dataset ChartJS Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, chart.js

I am fetching an array of datasets from an API that returns the following :

```
[
"[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,58,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]",
"[0,0,53,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]",
"[0,0,381,0,0,649,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]"
]
```

I need to iterate each one of the above in my Chart JS Linechart as shown below :

```
 var lineChartData = {
labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7','8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14','15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21','22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27','28','29','30','31'],
datasets: [{
  label: 'My First dataset',
  fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
  strokeColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
  pointColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
  pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
  pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
  pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
  data: dataset[0]
}, {
  label: 'My Second dataset',
  fillColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,0.2)',
  strokeColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
  pointColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
  pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
  pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
  pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
  data: dataset[1]
},
{
  label: 'My Third dataset',
  fillColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,0.2)',
  strokeColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
  pointColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
  pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
  pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
  pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
  data: dataset[2]
}]
```

The number of datasets fetched from the API are variable, so I may require x number of datasets on the Line Chart.

How do I loop the array in my dataset?

The logic I thought of :

```
var lineChartData = {
labels : [1,2,3..]
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
     datasets : [{
     data : array[i]}]
}
```

New Updated Code after Nina's Help :

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://www.autosys.xyz/api/v1/getAllEmpDailyData?clientid=132617";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {

  var lineChartData = { 
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31'], 
    datasets: [{ 
      label: 'My First dataset', 
      fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)', 
      strokeColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)', 
      pointColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)', 
      pointStrokeColor: '#fff', 
      pointHighlightFill: '#fff', 
      pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)', 
      data: null }, 
      { 
        label: 'My Second dataset', 
        fillColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,0.2)', 
        strokeColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)', 
        pointColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)', 
        pointStrokeColor: '#fff', 
        pointHighlightFill: '#fff', 
        pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)', 
        data: null }, 
        { 
          label: 'My Third dataset', 
          fillColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,0.2)', 
          strokeColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)', 
          pointColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)', 
          pointStrokeColor: '#fff', 
          pointHighlightFill: '#fff', 
          pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)', 
          data: null }] },
    array = arr;

array.forEach(function (a, i) {
    lineChartData.datasets[i].data = JSON.parse(a);
});

console.log(lineChartData);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer with help from Nina Scholz.

```
function getDataset(index, data) { 
return { 
label: 'Label '+ index, 
fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)', 
strokeColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)', 
pointColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)', 
pointStrokeColor: '#fff', 
pointHighlightFill: '#fff', 
pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)', 
data: data 
}; 
}


array.forEach(function (a, i) { 
lineChartData.datasets.push(getDataset(i,JSON.parse(a))); 
});

console.log(lineChartData);
```

Created a function getDataset within the parent function and iterated it using array.forEach function.

Thank you Nina for your help.

Comment: If anyone is getting undefined with lineChartData.datasets, try lineChartData.chart.data.datasets

Answer (score 7):

You could use a loop ([`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) and assign the parsed items ([`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)) of the array.

```js
var lineChartData = { labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31'], datasets: [] },
    array = ["[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,58,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]", "[0,0,53,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]", "[0,0,381,0,0,649,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]"];

array.forEach(function (a, i) {
    lineChartData.datasets.push({
        label: 'Label ' + i,
        fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        pointColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
        pointHighlightStroke:
        'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        data: JSON.parse(a)
    });
});

console.log(lineChartData);
```

Comment: This works only if I have 3 datasets, however the number of datasets are not fixed. They could be more than 3 also.

Comment: it works with more than 3. in the forEach is no limitation.

Comment: xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

Im using the above to get the dataset from the url api.
The code after linechartData = comes inside myfunction(arr)

Comment: The code I have mentioned above, var linechartData = { is inside the function myfunction(arr) { } which is called by the ajax api call method.

Comment: that's right. if you have a kind of static `lineChartData`.

Comment: It doesnt work, it shows nothing on the lineChart when I tried using the code you gave above.

Comment: On the console log yes, Uncaught Syntax Error : Unexpected Token

Comment: please have a look where the error occurs and try to fix it.

Comment: Fixed it, however there is another error now : charts-chartjs.html:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 6

Charts-chartsjs.html is the page im loading the line charts. and the first few lines are : Error at line 3

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: what is at position 6?

Comment: sorry, i can not help in this case.

Comment: you have some more data in the response. if you put it into the browser, you can see more data than the wanted array.

Comment: Which is exactly what my first comment to your answer was! I could have more data, the number of data is not fixed, I need to make it dynamic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117584/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-aaditya-damani).

Comment: I would appreciate a reply on chat :)

Answer (score -1):

Ninas answer completely worked

```html
<div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
       
        var lineChartData = {
            labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31'],
            datasets: []
        },
            array = [
                "[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,58,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]",
                "[0,0,53,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]",
                "[0,0,381,0,0,649,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]"
                    ];

        array.forEach(function (a, i) {
            lineChartData.datasets.push({
                label: 'Label ' + i,
                fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
                strokeColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                pointColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
                pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                pointHighlightStroke:
                    'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                data: JSON.parse(a)
            });
        });

        const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

        new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: lineChartData.labels,
                datasets: lineChartData.datasets
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```